# Proving $(U \cap V) \cap u(U \cap v) = (u \cap V)(U \cap v)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, alternative-proof, normal-subgroups

Let $U, V$ be subgroups of a group. Let $u \trianglelefteq U, v \trianglelefteq V$. I proved like this. Then by applying modular law,
$$\mathrm{(LHS)} = (U \cap V) \cap u(U \cap v) = U \cap V \cap uv \\
\mathrm{(RHS)} = (u \cap V)(U \cap v) = U \cap (u \cap V)v = U \cap V \cap uv \\
\therefore \mathrm{(LHS)} = \mathrm{(RHS)}$$
However I think it's overkill. Is there a shorter proof?

Comment: Tip: Don't make the whole subject a math formula; it prevents any number of actions. (For example, I like to right-click on questions and open them in a new tab, but if the whole subject is a formula, I can't: it just gives me options of how to see the code that produced it).

Comment: This looks plenty short to me...

Comment: The author used the equation immediately without proof(as if it's trivial) so I thought there is even simpler transformation technique

Comment: Now thst I think of it, applying modular law to RHS differently produces LHS immediately.